# How can I exit a docker container running alpine 3.3 with an error code?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, alpine-linux

How can I exit a docker container running alpine 3.3 with an error code?

Using: `image: "alpine:3.3"`

I have tried the following:

`command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "'exit 1'"]`

With the result:

> /bin/sh: exit 1: not found

I've also tried:

`command: ["/bin/sh", "exit", "1"]`

Which had a similar error.

The first thing I tried was:
`command: ["exit", "1"]`

Which resulted in:

> Error: failed to start container "post-install-job": Error response
>   from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345:
>   starting container process caused "exec: \"exit\": executable file not
>   found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: `sh -c` needs just one word, but it does not need to be double-quoted; `["/bin/sh", "-c", "exit 1"]`.

Comment: @DavidMaze this seems to have worked... if you reply with an answer I can accept it